# JPanels are not centered when using BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, layout-manager

I've been making a dumb little card trick to get back into Java after a few years and I've been having some difficulty in making JPanels go where I want them.

The components that are giving me trouble are chosenCard and label. Everything else sits nicely at the center. Each of the cardRow JPanels holds 7 cards and mainRow# holds the cardRow with a button next to it. each card is 74x98 so I tried to keep everything sized well.

Here's the Trick class that handles all the placements and layouts.

```
public Trick()
{
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(650, 600)); //set the size large enough to hold all panels neatly

    //Card row setup
    trickCards = new Deck().getCards(21);
    cardRow1 = new JPanel();
    cardRow2 = new JPanel();
    cardRow3 = new JPanel();

    cardRow1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650, 120));
    cardRow2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650, 120));
    cardRow3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650, 120));
    cardRow1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cardRow1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    cardRow2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cardRow2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    cardRow3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cardRow3, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    setToRows();

    button1 = new JButton("Row 1");
    button1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_1);
    button1.setActionCommand("1");
    button2 = new JButton("Row 2");
    button2.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_2);
    button2.setActionCommand("2");
    button3 = new JButton("Row 3");
    button3.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_3);
    button3.setActionCommand("3");

    group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(button1);
    group.add(button2);
    group.add(button3);
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    button3.addActionListener(this);

    chosenCard = new JPanel();
    chosenCard.setLayout(new BoxLayout(chosenCard, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    chosenCard.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 120));
    chosenCard.add(new Card(trickCards[1].getCardFace(), -1, -1));

    label = new JLabel("Card Trick! Pick any one card and click the row it is in [1, 2, 3]");
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));

    mainRow1 = new JPanel();
    mainRow2 = new JPanel();
    mainRow3 = new JPanel();
    mainRow1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 120));
    mainRow1.add(cardRow1);
    mainRow1.add(button1);
    mainRow2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 120));
    mainRow2.add(cardRow2);
    mainRow2.add(button2);
    mainRow3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 120));
    mainRow3.add(cardRow3);
    mainRow3.add(button3);

    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    add(mainRow1);
    add(mainRow2);  
    add(mainRow3);
    add(label);
    add(chosenCard);
}

//Refreshes what cards are in the rows
//Usually done after a selection is made

private void setToRows()
{
    cardRow1.removeAll();
    cardRow2.removeAll();
    cardRow3.removeAll();
    for(int x = 0; x < trickCards.length / 3; x++)
    {
        cardRow1.add(trickCards[x]);
        cardRow2.add(trickCards[x + (trickCards.length / 3)]);
        cardRow3.add(trickCards[x + ((trickCards.length / 3) * 2)]);
    }
}

//The listener for the buttons
//Will be expanded
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("1"))
    {
        System.out.println("1");
        label.setText("You chose 1!");
    }
    else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("2"))
    {
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("3"))
    {
        System.out.println("3");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("There's something wrong with the choice! Set to 0");
}
```

Comment: What is a SCCE? I'm at work and its blocked off for me..

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake, it's http://sscce.org/, which is a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example.

Comment: Most likely, this comes from the bad habit of using `setPreferredSize`. This is just fighting the system. Let the `LayoutManager`'s take care of that for you.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet When I do that, every card is cut off except for the upper left corner. However I was able to fix that by forcing the Card class (a JPanel with the image tacked on) into a preferred size of 75x100. But with the centering of the chosenCard and label components, they're still off to the left.

Comment: As long as you don't provide us more info, we won't be able to help you more. I have no idea on how you have implemented your Card's components, nor the rest of your program. All I can tell you is that using `setPreferredSize()` always leads to layout issues. Trying to add more will only throw more issues.

Comment: I resolved it by removed all BoxLayout instances except for the Trick panel.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your label is centered but the text in the label is not.

So set the text alignment to CENTER

```
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```